# How to make bitcoin lightning payment button on a web page launch android wallet app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, bitcoin

Imagine you've got a bitcoin lightning invoice address from your server:

```
 lnbc410u1pjnxtgvpp5jnkkyrp90n6kaa3ee3wg2tkdtuwf05m47x78c4pwhckc9hstr7psdqqcqzzsxqr8pqsp56sv208x5l422tjm4rgqg5k4hcrz548c703dtydnswcvfe7g5r2jq9qyyssq20gw3t39gr822q7vwvkus0h9s5zv54lm55x4pnyhfyqlvuf599s3ck450x7lnwe0jhk96zcmxx9j7afd9tk2e9c0afwr5xjwjay0xmqp9vdqr7
```

How could you make a button in a react application that can open this in your bitcoin lightning wallet, installed on your phone?

I've tried this:

```
  const handlePayment = (address, amount) => {
    console.log('handle btc payment', address, amount)
    const bitcoinURI = `bitcoin:${address}?amount=${amount}`;
    window.location.href = bitcoinURI;
  };
```

Which opens up my Bitcoin wallet, but then it throws the error (the provided payment details are invalid).

According to [this post](https://thebitcoinmanual.com/articles/create-lightning-payment-links/) I just needed to switch the wording from `bitcoin:` to `lightning:`

```
  const handlePayment = (address, amount) => {
    console.log('handle btc payment', address, amount)
    const bitcoinURI = `lightning:${address}`;
    window.location.href = bitcoinURI;
  };
```

But this doesn't work when testing with the Muun wallet. I get the same error as before. And in Wallet of Satoshi, the app opens, but just to the home page. It doesn't open the invoice to pay it or throw an error.